# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm geting this error

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84
>   bytes)
>   /url/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php
>   271

I've been testing it for a while but whenever the range between `$data1` and `$data2` is too big the error appears, still i gess the query should not be that hard for the server so I supose I'm actually doing something wrong with the query builder. Right now i'm reproducing the error by filtering only the dates and a single commerce.

```
function getTicketsList($tpv, $salesman, $customer, $data1, $data2){

if(count($tpv)==1){
    $tpv = array($tpv);
}

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

$qb
    ->select('t.id_tickets', 't.ticket_code', 's.name AS seller', 'c.name AS customer', 'c.surnames AS customer_s',
            't.created_client_date', 't.comment', '(t.total_amount - t.total_net_amount) AS tax_amount', 't.total_amount', 't.discount','c.email AS customer_email')
    ->join('Entity\Seller', 's', 'WITH', 's = t.seller')
    ->leftJoin('Entity\Customer', 'c', 'WITH', 'c = t.customer')
    ->distinct();


$filter = $qb->expr()->andx();

if($salesman){
    $filter->add(
            $qb->expr()->eq('t.seller','?1'));
    $qb->setParameter(1, $salesman);
}
else{
    $filter->add(
            $qb->expr()->in('t.tpv', ':tpv_id'));
    $qb->setParameter('tpv_id', $tpv);
}

if($customer){
    $filter->add(
            $qb->expr()->eq('t.customer','?2'));
    $qb->setParameter(2, $customer);
}

if($data1){
    $filter->add(
            $qb->expr()->gte('t.created_client_date', ':small_date'));
    $qb->setParameter('small_date', $data1);
}

if($data2){
    $filter->add(
            $qb->expr()->lte('t.created_client_date', ':big_date'));
    $qb->setParameter('big_date', $data2);
}

$qb->where($filter);


$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

return $result;

}
```

Does anybody notice some error, bad practice in my query builder function or have some suggestion to improve preformance?

Comment: Didi you tried this `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`

Comment: Employ pagination, simply you're fetching too many records at a time and are running out of memory

Comment: @Nebojsa yes and did not work, most probably there's some limitations from the hosting service(idk).

Comment: @malarzm executing the same query into Mysql Workbench returns a fast result of 3170 rows which made me think the problem was about doctrine or the way i'm executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code before line 271:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

It will temporarily set your php memory_limit to 2048M.